# Sql Query to Laravel Query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to change sql query to Laravel. 
But it makes error. Please help how to change this query.

(this query make ranking query. )

```
select school_id, id, month, ifnull(avg,0) as avg, ifnull(sum,0) as sum, 
@rank := @rank +1 as rank from v2_rank_status as s, (select @rank :=0 ) as r 
where month ='201901' order by sum desc
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to define `@rank` before using it;

```
DB::statement('SET @rank = 0'); //we start from 0 because the first query will have +1
DB::select('SELECT school_id, id, month, IFNULL(avg, 0) AS avg, IFNULL(sum,0) AS sum, @rank:=(@rank+1) AS rank FROM v2_rank_status WHERE month = ? order by sum desc', [
    '201901'
]);
```

This will set `@rank` to 0, and select with incrementing +1